# The Importance of First Impression in PhD Applications

Tags: phd, application

I have worked in the industry for the past few years, but am now applying for PhD. I do not have any significant research papers, but can get a few good ones published this year. I have shortlisted a few prospective professors, under whom I would like to work.

Should I apply this year itself? With a mediocre research resume, it is probable that they reject my application. This may leave a bad impression on them for my future application, when I apply again.

Or, should I wait for a year and work hard towards publishing a few papers, and then apply to these professors, next year?

To put the question in a different form: "*Will a mediocre resume implant a permanent bad impression?*"

Or, to put it even more generically : "*How much does the first impression weigh in academia?*"

Comment: Where are you applying? The country.

Comment: @Buffy US, Germany, Switzerland, and some other European countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, few entering students have much in the way of research. The usual case is that students enter doctoral programs without an MS or the equivalent. The earlier education is broad, not especially specialized. So, in the US, lacking research credentials should not be an impediment, provided that other things in your background point to success.

The situation in Europe is quite different as the undergraduate program there is more specialized. I'll let someone with more experience there answer for the EU. I suspect, however, that a few papers would be looked upon favorably.

But the path may be longer in the US, with some coursework prior to qualifying exams. Five to seven years past the BS is fairly typical, with the early part, again, not particularly research oriented. There are exceptions to this, of course, and it is possible to enter at a more advanced stage as long as you can pass the exams and find a suitable advisor.

And note that in the US, it is relatively uncommon that you enter knowing who your dissertation advisor will be. That choice is normally made later after you have narrowed your field. So a "first" impression with the advisor depends less on your CV at entry, and more on how you do in the first years.

But the question you actually ask (mediocre, first impression,...) is more subtle. You need an excellent CV and Statement of Purpose along with letters of recommendation. It is just more likely to be light on research in the US.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you also elaborate more on the "first impression" part? Today, my CV and SOP would be rated 6/10 (some arbitrary rating). But, next year, it should be rated 8/10. So, should I wait out a year or apply now? And, does this "first-impression" conundrum depend on the location where I am applying?

Comment: The "nature" of the impression matters and differs from place to place. I'm also a bit confused whether you mean a "personal" first impression or a professional one. For a personal impression, it is a mistake to project arrogance.

Comment: See my latest edit. I hope it is more clear.

Comment: I mean professional impression only. (Reposting this comment as I accidentally deleted it).

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the edit. It is clear now, at least in the case of US, that I do not need to wait :)